# Is there a Ruby, or Ruby-ism for not_nil? opposite of nil? method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I am not experienced in Ruby, so my code feels "ugly" and not idiomatic:

```
def logged_in?
  !user.nil?
end
```

I'd rather have something like

```
def logged_in?
  user.not_nil?
end
```

But cannot find such a method that opposites `nil?`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

when you're using ActiveSupport, there's `user.present?` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present%3F, to check just for non-nil, why not use

```
def logged_in?
  user # or !!user if you really want boolean's
end
```

Comment: I added a tag to my original post, indicating that -indeed- I am using Rails, hence the user.present? is present. AFAIK that indeed is the exact opposite of nil? Hence exactly what I need (in this context, a rails project)

Comment: Beware: `present?` requires a non-blank string.  `! "".nil?` returns true, but `"".present?` returns false.

Comment: Beware 2: I'll also note that !!user does NOT distinguish between user being nil and user being false; the double-bang usage conflates those two.  So if you're truly wanting to determine if an object is not nil (meaning, it's: true, false, 0, "", anything other than nil), you need to use the 'ugly' approach that berkes doesn't like or the monkeypatch that @Tempus [proposes below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4012786/492404).

Of course in this case where not nil is *not* needed (a user in Rails), [the approach taken by Samo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4016263/492404) is the least ugly, imo.

Comment: `false.present? == false` `!false.nil? == true`

Comment: This answer doesn't at all answer the question asked. It's an answer to this particular implementation problem.

Comment: This answer is not correct. false.nil? is false, while false.present? is ALSO false!

Answer (score 51):

You seem overly concerned with booleans.

```
def logged_in?
  user
end
```

If the user is nil, then logged_in? will return a "falsey" value. Otherwise, it will return an object. In Ruby we don't need to return true or false, since we have "truthy" and "falsey" values like in JavaScript.

**Update**

If you're using Rails, you can make this read more nicely by using the `present?` method:

```
def logged_in?
  user.present?
end
```

Comment: The expectation with a method ending with a `?` is that it returns a boolean. `!!value` is the classic way to convert anything to a boolean. Not exactly the same, but in this case `Object#present?` in RoR is also good.

Comment: this actually breaks in Ruby 2.4 with Path! [43] (pry) #<ReactOnRails::AssetsPrecompile>: 0> assets_path.blank?
true
[44] (pry) #<ReactOnRails::AssetsPrecompile>: 0> assets_path.to_s
"/var/folders/rp/_k99k0pn0rsb4d3lm9l3dnjh0000gn/T/d20170603-96466-zk7di7"
[45] (pry) #<ReactOnRails::AssetsPrecompile>: 0> assets_path.present?
false
[46] (pry) #<ReactOnRails::AssetsPrecompile>: 0> assets_path.nil?
false

Comment: Although this solves the specific problem, `.present?` is NOT the opposite of `.nil?`. In fact, it is the opposite of `.blank?`.

Comment: I was mislead by this answer, which resulted in a bug. I had `array.present?` and it returned false when the array was not nil, which occurred on an empty array. So essentially both `array.nil?` and `array.present?` returned false. So `array.present?` is not opposite of `array.nil?` because opposite means that both can never be true or false at the same time.

Comment: Last two comments are fair, `.present?` is not truly the opposite of `.nil?` which is what the question title asks for. The question itself makes clear that OP is looking for a way to determine if a variable has a non-empty value, so `.present?` is the recommendation even though it's not what the title specified.

This is neither the tone nor the format in which I'd answer a question today, but this is a 13 year old answer. I appreciate the corrections.

Answer (score 37):

Beware other answers presenting `present?` as an answer to your question.

`present?` is the opposite of `blank?` in rails.

`present?` checks if there is a meaningful value. These things can fail a `present?` check:

```
"".present? # false
"    ".present? # false
[].present? # false
false.present? # false
YourActiveRecordModel.where("false = true").present? # false
```

Whereas a `!nil?` check gives:

```
!"".nil? # true
!"    ".nil? # true
![].nil? # true
!false.nil? # true
!YourActiveRecordModel.where("false = true").nil? # true
```

`nil?` checks if an object is actually `nil`. Anything else: an empty string, `0`, `false`, whatever, is not `nil`.

`present?` is very useful, but definitely not the opposite of `nil?`. Confusing the two can lead to unexpected errors.

For your use case `present?` will work, but it's always wise to be aware of the difference.

Comment: Should be included in the accepted answer. `false.blank?` is not same as as `false.nil?`

Comment: `present?` will query your database, `nil?` will not, be careful with that

Answer (score 21):

Maybe this could be an approach:

```
class Object
  def not_nil?
    !nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: Good idea. I make from this that there is no not_nil? in Ruby. But should this not be `!self.nil?` rather then `!nil?`, or is `self`implicit?

Comment: You don't need self. It will be implied.

Comment: Self is implied when reading from instance methods (or accessors, which are really just methods). When setting values, a variable local to the method will be created before Ruby checks the class instance for a setter method of the same name. General rule: if you have an attr_accessor called xxx, use "self.xxx = 3" (setting a value) or "temp = xxx" (reading the value). Using "xxx = 3" will not update the accessor, just create a new variable in the method scope.

Answer (score 17):

May I offer the Ruby-esque `!` method on the result from the `nil?` method.

```
def logged_in?
  user.nil?.!
end
```

So esoteric that RubyMine IDE will flag it as an error. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the following:

```
if object
  p "object exists"
else
  p "object does not exist"
end
```

This does not only work for nil but also false etc, so you should test to see if it works out in your usecase.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived at this question looking for an object method, so that I could use the [`Symbol#to_proc` shorthand](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) instead of a block; I find `arr.find(&:not_nil?)` somewhat more readable than `arr.find { |e| !e.nil? }`.

The method I found is [`Object#itself`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself).  In my usage, I wanted to find the value in a hash for the key `name`, where in some cases that key was accidentally capitalized as `Name`.  That one-liner is as follows:

```
# Extract values for several possible keys 
#   and find the first non-nil one
["Name", "name"].map { |k| my_hash[k] }.find(&:itself)
```

As noted in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4012803/2063546), this will fail spectacularly in cases where you are testing a boolean.

Comment: How is that different from `my_hash.values_at("Name", "name").find`?

Comment: It's exactly the same.  I had some other logic in my original `map` that I removed for simplicity in this example, so as-written here it's interchangeable with `values_at`.  The important part is what gets passed to `find`.